# Assigning value to a variable from an asynchronous function

Tags: swift, string, firebase, asynchronous, closures

I am trying to add a variable in the String class, of type Bool, that if used on a userName as String, is supposed to check Firebase and return true if the username exists and false if not. In the end I am aiming to use it like this:

```
username.isUserNameAvailable
```

The problem is that my Firebase function returns data asynchronously. Therefore in my function below, variable isTaken, is assigned a value after variable availability is returned from the function. Is there a way to fix this?

```
fileprivate extension String {
    var isUserNameAvailable : Bool {
        var availability : Bool?
        DatabaseManager.system.isUserNameTaken(userName: self, completion: {(isTaken) in
            availability = !isTaken
            print("isTaken = \(isTaken)")
        })
        print("availability = \(availability)")
        return availability!
    } 
}
```

Comment: Declared as (computed) property it's impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't try to treat an asynchronous call as something that is already available.

I would suggest having a method that calls a code block when the Firebase request is finished.
Something like this:

```
fileprivate extension String {
  func isUserNameAvailable(completion: (Bool)->()) {
    DatabaseManager.system.isUserNameTaken(userName: self, completion:{(isTaken) in
      completion(!isTaken)
    })
  }
}
```

You would call it like this:

```
string.isUserNameAvailable { (available) in
  //use the variable
}
```

It's not exactly what you wanted, but it still simplifies the call while showing a bit more clearly that the call is asynchronous.